# How to pass massive data from flask to template?

Tags: python, flask, datatables, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I have the data that get from database, the data is about more that 30,000 record, when i render the template with these data, the template is very slow, so what is the best way to pass the massive data and display on template.

This is my code.

route.py

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
  asset_table = asset.query.all()
  return render_template('index.html', asset_table=asset_table)
```

index.html

```
 <table class="table table-hover table-sm table-striped" id="asset_table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">

        <tr>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

            {% for asset in asset_table %}

                    <tr>
                    <td>{{ asset.asset_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ asset.asset_name }}</td>
                    </tr>
            {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
    </table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#asset_table').DataTable({
                "scrollX": true,
            });
            $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');



    });

</script>
```

models.py

```
from application import db

class asset(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'asset'
    asset_id = db.Column(db.String(30), primary_key=True)
    asset_name = db.Column(db.String(30))
```

Comment: You're trying to put 30,000 records onto the screen? Would it work for you to break these into batches of, say, 1,000 records? Are users actually using them on the screen or just downloading them into a csv or excel file?

Comment: @Ben using on the screen, and the template will have input field for search query to get the data that user want.

Comment: @Ben And i using the DataTables plug-in to implement these data with limit row record and pagination. Which i just update on my code.

Comment: Why don't you try server side processing  https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side?

Comment: @Kartikeya Sharma I think this is what i looking for, but cloud you please show me i sample example that passing the data  to datatables with server side processing.

Comment: Could you also insert your models script for that table?

Comment: @Kartikeya Sharma models script of my db ?

Comment: yes exactly models.py

Comment: @Kartikeya Sharma i just added `models.py` on my question pal.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a library called [sqlalchemy-datatables](https://github.com/Pegase745/sqlalchemy-datatables) which is a bit old now but does it work.

The code should look like this:

Flask Code

```
from datatables import ColumnDT, DataTables

@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
def index():
  """
  Code which renders the index page
  """
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/data', methods=['GET'])
def data():
  """
  Returns data for the index page.
  GET:
        params:
            Please learn about the other parameters here:
                https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters
        responses:
            Please learn about the response parameters here:
                https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data
  """
  columns = [
    ColumnDT(
       asset.asset_id,
       mData="ID" 
     ),
    ColumnDT(
       asset.asset_name,
       mData="Name"
     )
              ]
  query = db.session.query().select_from(asset)
  params = request.args.to_dict()
  rowTable = DataTables(params, query, columns)
  return jsonify(rowTable.output_result())
```

HTML/Jquery Code

```
<table class="table table-hover table-sm table-striped" id="asset_table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    </table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#asset_table').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: "{{ url_for('data')}}",
                dom: 'Bflrtip',
                columns: [
                        { "data": "ID" },
                        { "data": "Name" },]
            });
    });

</script>
```

Cheers!